# Tomcat crashes Eclipse Kepler with "Failed to write core dump."

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

After upgrading my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 I've faced some problems on deploying my application with Tomcat in Eclipse. When I run my application, Tomcat starts successfully, and then, before the internal Eclipse web-browser opening, it crashes, giving me the next log file:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f50a9c90ca9, pid=19115, tid=139985944897280
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_55-b13) (build 1.7.0_55-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0+0x461ca9]  webkit_web_view_get_type+0x2489
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f50fc00a000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=19118, stack(0x00007f510474e000,0x00007f510484f000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
....
....
....
---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:jessie/sid

uname:Linux 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.19 NPTL 2.19 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 15837, NOFILE 4096, AS infinity
load average:1,41 1,37 1,59

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:        2048668 kB
MemFree:           72176 kB
Buffers:            3084 kB
Cached:           302944 kB
SwapCached:         1704 kB
Active:          1308052 kB
Inactive:         498300 kB
Active(anon):    1213508 kB
Inactive(anon):   404816 kB
Active(file):      94544 kB
Inactive(file):    93484 kB
Unevictable:          32 kB
Mlocked:              32 kB
SwapTotal:       1999868 kB
SwapFree:        1877512 kB
Dirty:               412 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:       1498712 kB
Mapped:           202676 kB
Shmem:            118016 kB
Slab:              65584 kB
SReclaimable:      36836 kB
SUnreclaim:        28748 kB
KernelStack:        4056 kB
PageTables:        35320 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3024200 kB
Committed_AS:    4928148 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:      325620 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359354596 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:    124928 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       56192 kB
DirectMap2M:     2039808 kB


CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

/proc/cpuinfo:
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E4600  @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 13
microcode   : 0xa1
cpu MHz     : 2400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
bogomips    : 4799.49
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 15
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E4600  @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 13
microcode   : 0xa1
cpu MHz     : 2400.000
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 2
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
bogomips    : 4799.49
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:



Memory: 4k page, physical 2048668k(72052k free), swap 1999868k(1877512k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.55-b03) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_55-b13), built on Mar 17 2014 19:43:58 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Sat May 10 20:05:03 2014
elapsed time: 351 seconds
```

I've read the recommended issues on this staff, but nothing helped. (There are no so much of them.) Also, I've noticed that with using not the internal Eclipse web-browser, but the external one (Firefox, etc.) there are no such a problem. So, the thing that crashes my application is somehow connected with this internal web-browser. If somebody also had such a problem and found the issue, please help.

Answer (score 4):

This just worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get remove libwebkitgtk-1.0-0
sudo apt-get insert libwebkitgtk-3.0-0
```